# Additional Metadata Attribute Ignored – in one instance of VS2010 but not the other

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I have 2 copies of VS2010 Ultimate, one running on a box with XP SP3 and the other on Win7; both 32 bit.  Both are otherwise identical, as far as I can tell.

I created a little test MVC3 project including a simple model with a couple of AdditionalMetadata attributes on it.  Run the ap on the XP box with breakpoints at appropriate places in the view and sure enough, there are my AdditionalMetadata values where I expect under ViewData > ModelMetadata > AdditionalValues.

I copy the project to my Win7 machine and load it into that copy of VS 2010.  Builds fine.  Run it in debug mode and… no sign of the AdditionalMetadata values. It's as though they were not added to the model.

I just upgraded both copies to SP1 with no effect.  Is there a funky setting somewhere I’m missing?  I dread having to rebuild the machine.

Here’s my simple model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Tp4.Models
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.AdditionalMetadata("AdditionalKey1", "Foo")]
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [UIHint("PlaceholderString")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.AdditionalMetadata("AdditionalKey2", "Bar")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved it by uninstalling and reinstalling MVC3.